# How to mock React stateless currying function using Jest & Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have this stateless React component:

```
...
const Providers = ({ onSelectFeedProvider, ... }) => {
  const handleSelectFeedProvider = value => e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onSelectFeedProvider({ target: { value } });
  };

  return {
    <Row onClick={handleSelectFeedProvider(1)}>
      ...
    </Row>
  }
}
```

And the test:

```
import Row from 'components/Common/Row';
import Providers from './index';

jest.mock('components/Common/Row', () => 'Row');

let onSelectFeedProviderSpy = jest.fn();
let onSelectProviderSpy = jest.fn();

const initialProps = {
  feedProvider: 0,
  onSelectFeedProvider: () => onSelectFeedProviderSpy(),
  selectedProvider: undefined,
  onSelectProvider: () => onSelectProviderSpy()
};

const mockComponent = props => {
  const finalProps = { ...initialProps, ...props };

  return <Providers {...finalProps} />;
};

it('should call correctly', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(mockComponent());

  wrapper.find(Row).simulate('click', 'what do I have to do here');

  expect(onSelect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

How can I do to call the method correctly and pass the coverage? I think have tried all the possibilities. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have many options in this, one approach is to have `onSelect` injectable

```js
const Component = ({onSelect}) => {
  const handleSelect = value => e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    onSelect && onSelect({ target: { value } })
  }

  return <Row onClick={handleSelect(1)} />
}
```

Test

```js
it('should call correctly', () => {
  const spy = jest.fn()
  const wrapper = shallow(mockComponent({onSelectProvider: spy}));

  wrapper.find(Row).simulate('click', 'what do I have to do here');

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I also want to pass the coverage. Whit this solution it does not pass.

Comment: Than probably you need to post full example, because in your snippet `onSelect` is undefined. If you show full component maybe we can alter my answer to have full coverage

Comment: I updated my answer with test, why you don't just pass `onSelectProvider` to `mockComponent` ? It accepts the props and will overwrite the `onSelectProvider` method in component and should also gave full coverage

Comment: Because the problem is in the shallow of the function. When I simulate the click, it expects to be a function and not a currying. So my question is how can I simulate clicking a currying function.

Comment: Maybe don't curry it ? :D Just deal with your destiny and do `onClick={e => handleSelect(e, 1) }`

Comment: Well, that's the last option but for performance it's better not to bind because it avoid creating a brand new callback instance on every render